# How to combine dynamic fields and DB::raw with Laravel's fluent query builder?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, fluent

This is my desired SQL:

```
SELECT 
    p.id , p.title , p.msrp , i.files
    , p.cost
FROM 
    `products` p
    LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT 
            GROUP_CONCAT( `images`.`filename` SEPARATOR ',' ) AS files , `product_id` 
        FROM 
            `images` 
        GROUP BY 
            `product_id` 
    ) i ON i.product_id = p.id
```

Here is my query using Laravel's fluent query builder:

```
$products = DB::table( 'products as p' )
    ->where( 'p.active' , '=' , 1 )
    ->select( $fields )
    ->get();
```

The `$fields` variable is an array of fields based on whether the user is logged in or not:

```
$fields = array( 'p.id' , 'p.title' , 'p.msrp' , 'i.files' ) ;
if( Auth::check() ) array_push( $fields , 'p.cost' ) ;
```

I am trying the LEFT JOIN using `DB::raw`:

```
->leftJoin(DB::raw( "( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( images.filename SEPARATOR ',' ) , product_id FROM images GROUP BY product_id ) i" , "i.product_id", "=" , "p.id" )
```

For some reason this is not working... am I doing something wrong?  I need to use `DB::raw` so that I can `GROUP_CONCAT` multiple rows in the `images` table into a delimited string.

On a tangent... I think sub-query select is not supported so if anyone has a better option, please let me know.